# How to get a string of different colors

Tags: javascript, html

As a result of the script execution, I have a combined string concatenation of two, how to make the first part of the resulting line colored red, and the second blue

```js
function generateFullName() {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById('fName').value;
  var elem2 = document.getElementById('lName').value;

  document.getElementById('fullName').innerText = elem1 + ' ' + elem2;
}
```

```html
First Name
<param type="text" id="fName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" class='tsvet' value="2" /><br/> Last Name
<param type="text" id="lName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" value="354" /><br/> Full Name <span id="fullName" class='tsvet' />

<body onload="generateFullName();"> </body>
```

Comment: I have removed the link to the fiddle. Please read: [How do I create a runnable snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Why haven't you just added CSS?

Comment: As part of my platform, I can not use the CSS file

Comment: @forsenlol Never said you should use CSS file you could just add `<style>#fname{color:red}</style>` anywhere in the html page

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`innerHTML`**](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead `innerText`

```js
function generateFullName() {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById('fName').value;
  var elem2 = document.getElementById('lName').value;

  document.getElementById('fullName').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">' + elem1 + '</span><span style="color:blue"> ' + elem2 + '</span>';
}
```

```html
First Name
<param type="text" id="fName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" class='tsvet' value="2" /><br/> Last Name
<param type="text" id="lName" onkeyup="generateFullName()" value="354" /><br/> Full Name <span id="fullName" class='tsvet' />

<body onload="generateFullName();"> </body>
```